# Typescript throws error with spread operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following simple React component:

```
export interface BadgeProps {
  children: React.ReactNode | string | React.ReactNode[],
  layout: "gray" | "danger" | "success" | "brand",
  size?: "sm" | "base",
}

const Badge: React.FC<BadgeProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div data-test="component-badge">{children}</div>
  );
}
```

When I now call the component this way it works fine:

```
<Badge layout="gray">Text</Badge>
```

But when I pass the props with a spread operator, I get the following error.

```
const props = { layout: "gray" };
return (
  <Badge {...props}>Text</Badge>
);
```

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"gray" | "danger" | "success" | "brand"'

I feel like it should just work fine and I have no idea why it fails. Is this a misunderstanding of how Typescript works?

Comment: Try `const props = { layout: "gray" } as const;` or `const props = { layout: "gray" as const };`.  TypeScript has to infer the type of `props` and it thought you wanted the `layout` property widened to `string`; maybe you wanted to assign some different `string` properties to it like `props.layout = "cheese sticks"`. It didn't know you needed it to be kept narrow.  It's sorry, it's doing the best it can 

Comment: Did you try using an enum instead? Doesn't answer the main issue behind the error, but could be a solution to give your props into the Component.

Comment: @jcalz that worked, thank you

Comment: @JonathanStellwag Thought about enum as well but I found it a bit annoying to import the enum as well when trying to use the component. Can you tell me what the advantages of using an enum are compared to my approach?

Comment: @MaxTommyMitschke enums are usually better than string literals. It's easier to refactor, find usages. Also, if you don't need to get names of enum during runtime, you should use const enum. Const enums are completely removed and their values are hard coded during runtime. See the [diff](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgTwM5QN4CgpagWQPYgAmiANJtgCpjBLEJnZQDqwhINd6AvuugMYEkeADbAAdMLwBzABTxkY-EUQBKANz9BI8ZNnykYqh1UaBIIaInS5iAyzbGE63maQAXKKEhQAwoLf6aORYSnQMlNS0pMHMrOxRCNwuWpa6Mn7mAbaKBHTOrtpWshnu+oaReaYpOtYlWQr28ZVAA)

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner explained it very well. Also one advantage is that it might work. In this post you can see how const enums are transpiled: https://twitter.com/sulco/status/1049361905914204161

Answer (score 1):

It because `"gray" | "danger" | "success" | "brand"` is a specific type that can be only one of those strings, but when you assigning like this:

```
const props = { layout: "gray" };
```

Typescript infers that `layout` property is a **string** and not your special type, therefore the error.

In order to fix this error, you need to mark the type yourself.

```
export type LayoutType = "gray" | "danger" | "success" | "brand";

export interface BadgeProps {
  children: React.ReactNode | string | React.ReactNode[],
  layout: LayoutType,
  size?: "sm" | "base",
}

const Badge: React.FC<BadgeProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div data-test="component-badge">{children}</div>
  );
}



const props: { layout: LayoutType } = { layout: "gray" };
// ------------------------^ your layout type 
return (
  <Badge {...props}>Text</Badge>
);
```